# How to exec javascript on page using and session handling with Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

How do I make Selenium exec all javascript on the page? Is a way to make it behave exactly like a browser (javascript, cookies handling, modifying headers of requests)?

`<script type="text/javascript" id="d__inj" class="d__inj_delayed" src="/cb-xzvuwrsbqbewye.js" defer=""></script>`

The above code on the website is never executed

Comment: can you elaborate on what the problem is and what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Selenium isn't a browser, it's an interface to the browser. Put a breakpoint in the line that fails and run your test. Once it stops, investigate the page. Hopefully at that point you can figure out what is going wrong.

Comment: I'll explain the problem I'm trying to solve. There are many bot detection services out there that uses javascript, cookie, header validation and redirects to detect if the request is coming from a bot. I'm just thinking there must be a solution so that the requests I'm sending in code are exactly the same as if they were send from a browser. Is selenium able to do that?